# Show that if $X_{n} \sim Y_{n}$ then $Y_{n}\sim X_{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

The definition of $\sim$ is $X_{n} \sim Y_{n} \Leftrightarrow X_{n} = Y_{n}(1 + o(1))$

This what I tried to do:

If $X_{n} \sim Y_{n}$ then $X_{n} = Y_{n}(1 + o(1))$ thus giving us $Y_{n}=X_{n}-Y_{n}(o(1))$  and so $X_{n} - Y_{n} = Y_{n}o(1)$

By definition of $o$ we have:

$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists n_{0} \in \mathbb{N},\: if \: n\geq n_{o} $ then we have $|X_{n} - Y_{n}| \leq \epsilon |1|$.

We have then $|X_{n}-Y_{n}| \leq \epsilon |1| \Leftrightarrow |Y_{n}-X_{n}| \leq \epsilon |1|$ which show that $Y_{n}-X{n}=o(1)$ thus $Y_{n}=X_{n}(1 + o(1))$. So $Y_{n} \sim X_{n}$.

Is my proof correct? Rigrous enough?

Comment: Definition of $\sim$?

Comment: @WWK Wrote the definition in the edit!

Comment: Bumping up this post.